# NewtonSoft JsonConverter and the slash character

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to create a dictionary from a Json array returned from a Web API which contains a file path value. I have extracted a sample here

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("[{'Path':'\6\6553_20140729_134527059.mp3'}]")
```

Various combinations produce the following error. Only 1 approach works and I would love to know why. If someone can help.. much appreciated

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1
```

The following throw the above error

```
//Escape with double slash
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("[{'Path':'\\6\\6553_20140729_134527059.mp3'}]")

//Escape with quadruple slash
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("[{'Path':'\\\\6\\\\6553_20140729_134527059.mp3'}]")

//Multiple Json Objects in array
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("[{'Path':'\\6\\6553_20140729_134527059.mp3'},{'Path':'\\6\\6553_20140729_134527059.mp3'}]")

//Double slash, single Json object
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("{'Path':'\\6\\6553_20140729_134527059.mp3'}")
```

This is the only thing that works

```
//Quadruple slash, single object 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>("{'Path':'\\\\6\\\\6553_20140729_134527059.mp3'}")
```

Like I said earlier, any help would be much appreciated

ALL THE TESTS DONE IN VISUAL STUDIO QUICK WATCH

Comment: See your error message **`Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.String]'`**  Your json is array/list. Try to deserialize `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When JSON starts with "[", it means that it represents List/Array, so the deserializer expect a List of some kind as  parameter, 
`List<Dictionary<string, string>>` in your case.